# Mac: Cannot open the parent directory Library

Tags: mac, permissions, osx-lion

I'm trying to access the Library folder on my OS Lion however all the tutorials related to this subject involves opening the user library however I would like to access the Library where the 'WebServer' folder is located when you enable web-sharing.

Whenever I try to access it it gives me the error that I am not allowed to see what's inside and I checked my status, saying that I am an admin but it still occurs. Why is this?

Comment: Look at the properties of Library. Go to the folder and press Commans+I, look at the bottom where it says 'Sharing & permissions' (expand if necessary). Another although unlikely possibility - are you sure that you are trying to access the system-wide Library? There are per-user Library folders (although hidden in Lion), if you are trying to access Library for another user it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah, I am trying to access system-wide library. The strangest thing though, when I go to system references -> sharing  and when I click on "Open website folder" I can access that folder. However when I simply go to my computer (cmd + shift + c) , click on my hard drive and click library it returns me an error message saying that I'm not allowed to list whats in there.

Comment: Try something else -- go to Terminal.app (in Applications -> Utilities) and type "ls -laF / | grep Library" (without the quotation marks, note that there is space between / and |). This should give you the permissions. It is basically the same thing that you could see under 'Sharing and Permissions'. On my machine it is "drwxr-xr-x+  <snip> root      wheel  <snip> Library/'. The drwxr-xr-x+, root and wheel indicate permissions, owner and group.

Comment: Run the `Repair Disk Permissions` option under Disk Utility.